# Last character of a string is not being recognized

Tags: java

I was just challenging myself with a simple java program that does the following: 1.) it accepts two string parameters: the first a string and the second a smaller sub-string.  The program is supposed to tell the user how many times the sub-string is contained in the string.  Also, if there are '?' in the string they should be treated like wildcard characters and automatically match any character.
Here's my code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String full_string = "jre?jokllljdg?kajf?b?argujbvabvaz";
        String sub_strings[] = {"jbva","eljz","klll","gujb","jrex","bvaz"};
        for (int x = 0; x < sub_strings.length; x++) {
            findTheSubString(full_string, sub_strings[x]);
        }
    }

    public static void findTheSubString(String full_string, String substring) {
        char[] full_chars = full_string.toCharArray();
        char[] sub_chars  = substring.toCharArray();
        int number_of_chars_matched = 0;
        int number_of_substrings_found = 0;
        int num = 0;
        for(char letter : full_chars) {
            char current_substring_letter = sub_chars[num];
            if ( (Character.toUpperCase(current_substring_letter) == Character.toUpperCase(letter)) || (letter == '?') ) {
                number_of_chars_matched++;
                num++;
            } else {
                number_of_chars_matched = 0;
                num = 0;
            }

            if ( number_of_chars_matched == sub_chars.length ) {
                number_of_substrings_found++;
                number_of_chars_matched = 0;
                num = 0;
            }
        }

        if ( number_of_substrings_found == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("No Matches!");
        } else if ( number_of_substrings_found > 0 ) {
            System.out.println("found "+number_of_substrings_found+" substrings!");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am encountering is, this is working well until you have a sub_string that matches the last tail end of the full_string, such as: "bvaz".  It doesn't process the last character in the substring on that iteration.  I'm really not sure why and was wondering if any of you pros could help me learn why?
Thanks and regards,
Joe

Comment: I don't think the problem is particularly that it ends with `bvaz`, but rather that `bvaz` is immediately preceded by `bva`, but you're not resetting to re-check the second `b` of `bvab`. Try reducing `full_string` to just `bvabvaz`, and see if the same problem happens; then, try stepping through with a debugger.

Comment: I am sure that the problem is as described in previous comment - posted algorithm will always fail if a substring is preceded by part of that substring - for given example (`bvabvaz`) if will match the first three letters and fail at the fourth (`b` instead of `z`) and will discard the second `b`, starting over at the second `v` -- basically it should go back to the second letter and start over from there

Comment: question: with word `banana` and substring `a?a` count 1 (just b_ana_na) or 2 (b_ana_na and ban_ana_) ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the substring is present at the last tail end, but in your full_string, the end is `bvabvaz` and you are failing to recheck the `b` that you would have checked during your previous check as first three characters would have matched your substring.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < full_chars.length ; i++) {
                char current_substring_letter = sub_chars[num];
                if ( (Character.toUpperCase(current_substring_letter) == Character.toUpperCase(full_chars[i])) || (full_chars[i] == '?') ) {
                    number_of_chars_matched++;
                    num++;
                } else {
                    if(number_of_chars_matched > 1 && i-1 > 0) i--;
                    number_of_chars_matched = 0;
                    num = 0;
                }
    
                if ( number_of_chars_matched == sub_chars.length ) {
                    number_of_substrings_found++;
                    if(number_of_chars_matched > 1 && i-1 > 0) i--;
                    number_of_chars_matched = 0;
                    num = 0;
                }
 }
```

To solve this, you just need to recheck the last character whenever you are setting the `number_of_chars_matched = 0`. But be careful, simply decrementing the index by 1 will cause problems when the number of characters matched during previous check is of length 1. It will result in a infinite loop.

Replacing your for loop with the above code should do the trick. To have more control of the indices, I converted the for-each loop to for loop. Then this condition is the one responsible for rechecking the character.

> `if(number_of_chars_matched > 1 && i-1 > 0) i--;`